# Call Vue JS method outside ViewModel

Tags: javascript, viewmodel, browserify, vue.js

I would like to know if it is possible to call a method inside an instance outside its scope. To make my question clear, I have the following setup:

HTML:

```
<header>
    ....
    <li class="main-navigation__item">
        <a href="#" v-on:click="showModal('login')" title="Inloggen" class="main-navigation__link">Inloggen</a>
    </li>
    ...
</header>

<div class="modal-container">
    <script type="x/template" id="modal-login">
        <div class="modal js-modal" v-show="show">
        ....
        </div>
    </script>
    <modal-login :show.sync="login"></modal-login>
</div>
```

JS:

```
// modals
Vue.component('modal-login', {
  template: '#modal-login',
  props: {
    show: {
      type: Boolean,
      required: true,
      twoWay: true
    }
  }
});

// modal container
module.exports = new Vue({
  el:'.modal-container',
  data: {
    login: false,
    register: false,
    reset: false
    methods: {
        showModal: function(modal) {
        ...
});
```

main.js file with Browserify:

```
var modal = require('./modules/modal');
```

To be more specific how can I call the method 'showModal' from inside the header thus outside the .modal-container instance?

Should everything belong in a wrapper('app') which holds all of its components or is this a correct vue js approach and am I missing something here?

EDIT:

Little example in JSFiddle to demonstrate:
https://jsfiddle.net/9hkboajb/
I would like to call the method showModal from within the header.

Comment: You have to provide more information. were do you add the modal component to? where do you add the header? Generally, components can only talk to their parent or child, for other communication, you have to use shared state objects or similar patterns. How exactly to do that in your situation is hard to say with this little information. Sidenote: Don't export Vue instances (`newVue(...)`) - just export the options object.

Comment: I have made an example in JSFiddle see the edits. What do you mean with exporting the options object, do you have an example of that?